# Read storage struct from a modifier

Tags: solidity, storage, struct, modifiers

If i read a struct(storage) `Human storage human = humans[2];` in my modifier is there a possibility that the function that uses this modifier can use the "human"? Otherwise i have to scope the storage again in my function.

Comment: Your question is unreadable. Please post the relevant code (function, state variable and modifier) properly.

Answer (score 2):

> is there a possibility that the function that uses this modifier can use the "human"

No. Nothing scoped in a modifier is available in a modified function.

> Otherwise i have to scope the storage again in my function.

Right.

Simple example with memory variable:

```
pragma solidity 0.5.1;

contract Scope {

    modifier checkScope {
        uint x = 100;
        _;
    }

    function doSomething() public pure checkScope returns(uint) {
        //return x; // can't use it
    }
}
```

Or more like your code:

```
pragma solidity 0.5.1;

contract Scope {

    struct Human {
        bool b;
    }

    Human[] humans;

    modifier checkScope {
        Human storage human = humans[2];
        _;
    }

    function doSomething() public view checkScope returns(bool) {
        // return human.b; // will not compile
        return humans[2].b; // works
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.